# Display Discount Amount on minicart Magento 1.9

Tags: php

I would like to display discount & tax amount on minicart for magento 1.9, but the following code display as 0 figure

```
<div class="subtotal">
    <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
        <span class="map-cart-sidebar-total"><?php echo $this->__('ORDER TOTAL WILL BE DISPLAYED BEFORE YOU SUBMIT THE ORDER'); ?></span>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Cart Discount:') ?></span> <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getDiscountAmount()) ?>
        <?php if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax()): ?>
            <br />
            <span class="incl-tax">(<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true) ?>)</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>

<div class="subtotal">
    <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
        <span class="map-cart-sidebar-total"><?php echo $this->__('ORDER TOTAL WILL BE DISPLAYED BEFORE YOU SUBMIT THE ORDER'); ?></span>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span class="label"><?php echo $this->__('Cart Tax:') ?></span> <?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($this->getTaxAmount()) ?>
        <?php if ($_subtotalInclTax = $this->getSubtotalInclTax()): ?>
            <br />
            <span class="incl-tax">(<?php echo Mage::helper('checkout')->formatPrice($_subtotalInclTax) ?> <?php echo Mage::helper('tax')->getIncExcText(true) ?>)</span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `minicart` block is an instance of class `Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar`, which doesn't have method `getDiscountAmount` or `getTaxAmount` defined.

You can use `$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getTaxAmount()` and `$this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getDiscountAmount()`